# Clarifications on a python script file

Tags: python

Just need some clarification on how to design a python script file  test.py.

1. When defining functions, do they have to go on the top of the file right after the imports?
2. should I be doing that **main** check in my file?
3. I want to run this file on my server as a cron job.  If the file gets too big (I have my sqlalchemy definitions in it also), how can I break the file into multiple files?  I want this easy to deploy by just dropping the files into a folder in my server.

Comment: Do this, please.  First, read PEP 8: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.  Second, after reading, update your question to mention specific things you didn't understand in PEP-8.  This is already answered in PEP 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most scripts look something like the following:

```
import module1
import module2

CONSTANT=...

def foo():
   ...

def bar():
   ....

class Baz():
   ....

def run(verbose=False):
    ....

if __name__=='__main__':
    import optparse
    def parse_options():
        usage = 'usage: %prog [options]'
        parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage=usage)
        parser.add_option('-v', '--verbose', dest='verbose',
                          action='store_true', 
                          default=False,
                          help="verbose")
        return parser.parse_args()
    def cli():
        opt,args=parse_options()        
        run(verbose=opt.verbose)
    cli()
```

So the body of your script is mainly composed of function/class definitions. There (usually) is very little code that isn't inside a function/class definition.

I would try to group the functions in whatever way facilitates organization and readability. If you believe a function can be reused in places other than that particular script, then place it in a module, and import that module into this script.

Define `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH` in your crontab. Then you should have no problem running your script from cron.

Comment: great, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: what about args that you pass when calling the script from command line?

Comment: @Blankman: I use the `optparse` module from the standard library to handle arguments from the command line. If you use Python2.7 or better, you might want to consider the `argparse` module which I believe is intended to replace optparse. I'll edit my answer to show the structure for optparse.

Comment: +100 awesome, I was thinking of adding a 'verbose' option, so bascially I can output print statements if verbose is set right? thanks a bunch!